# Magento Commerce Customer registration page field input appear incorrectly

Tags: layout, magento-2-commerce, customer-registration

we are currently in the process of setup magento2.3.5p2 commerce, previously we are using the magento2.3.5p2 open source version

After finish setup and installation of magento2.3.5p2 commerce at local, we copy all the necessary source code from open source into commerce version

After running all necessary command to upgrade, dicompile, reindex and cache clean, I noticed that the sign up page seems to be different

It appear like below the layout and input which are not correct

[image]

It should appear the same as in the open source which is as below

[image]

I tried to compare the source code in commerce and open source but they seem to be no different

Only after I remove certain source code part of email input at

`vendor/magento/module-customer-custom-attributes/view/frontend/templates/customer/form/register.phtml`

I can see that the bottom input part of the email field got removed

but I am not sure what is causing the layout change and why the email input at the bottom appear in commerce but not in open source

Comment: I found out this issue happen due to the source code at ```app/design/frontend/MageBig/martfury/layout01/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml``` are being read in the open source but not in commerce thus causing the layout not same as in open source

Comment: I am able to fix the issue, for some reason the code in ```app/design``` is not readable by magento commerce so I need to create new ```customer_account_create.xml``` based on vendor  then set the template to custom template from ```app/design``` now the template is updated

Comment: At my local its fixed, but for some reason at magento commerce staging it appear empty pages at signup page after the fix is implemented, not sure why